# ss utility does't work properly

Tags: linux, kernel, sles, netstat

I've learned that ss, which is base on netlink, [is much faster than netstat](http://www.cyberciti.biz/files/ss.html) when amount of sockets is large. And the secret is [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7356).

But when I tested on my suse linux minutes ago, the result confused me. 
It seems ss can't work properly(my linux kernel version is 2.6.16.46).

If I'm not get it wrong, this man page ( http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/netlink.7.html) indicates that my linux version should be ok to run ss.

Here is what I've got using strace:

```
sles10sp1:/usr/src/net-tools-1.60# strace ss -ant 2>&1 | grep sendmsg**
sendmsg(3, ..., 0) = -1 ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)***
```

What's going on here?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: In what way did the result confuse you? What is the result you got ?

Comment: sendmsg shouldn't return -1 if ss works properly

Answer (score 0):

We've found Redhat version 5 doesn't have support for ss (kernel version too low).
However, Centos-6 does support it (kernel version sufficient).

uname -a shows:
...   2.6.32-358.0.1.el6.x86_64 ...